# Overriding property with generic type of generic base class

Tags: swift, generics, inheritance

Here is what I want to do:

```swift
protocol GenericFactory {
    associatedtype Input
    associatedtype Value
    func create(with input: Input) -> Value
}

class Base<Factory: GenericFactory> {
    var input: Factory.Input {
        preconditionFailure("To be overriden")
    }
}

protocol ValueProtocol {}
struct SomeInputImpl {}

protocol ValueFactory: GenericFactory where Input == SomeInputImpl, Value: ValueProtocol {}

class Child<Factory: ValueFactory>: Base<Factory> {
    override var input: Factory.Input {
        return SomeInputImpl()
    }
}
```

On the line `swift override var input: Factory.Input {` I'm getting an error `Property 'input' with type 'SomeInputImpl' cannot override a property with type 'Factory.Input'`. I do not understand the reason of this error as the type of input is described in `ValueFactory` protocol, but because of some reasons swift interprets the Factory.Input in base and Factory.input in Child as different types. Can someone please explain me what's wrong here?

Comment: This is a limitation of Swift 4.2 that is resolved in Swift 5. The above code compiles in the latest Xcode beta. But I'd really like to talk with you about what you're trying to build here. This is almost certainly unnecessarily complicated, and can be solved much more easily other ways. As a teacher, I'm trying to understand why developers go down this road, and this question is exactly one I've been looking for a concrete example of. I would be very grateful if you would contact me about the concrete problem you're trying to solve at rob@neverwood.org, or by chatting further here.

Answer (score 2):

Just to complete the point about this being addressed in Swift 5, here is the demonstration that will work in Swift 5, but not in Swift 4.2, given your example code.

```
struct Val: ValueProtocol {}

struct VF: ValueFactory {
    func create(with input: SomeInputImpl) -> Val {
        return Val()
    }
}

let child = Child<VF>()
child.input  // SomeInputImpl
```

But you would almost certainly be better off using functions rather than `GenericFactory`. The main reason for the Factory pattern is to deal with languages that lack higher-order functions and first-class types, such as pre-8 Java. In languages with higher-order functions and first-class types (like Swift), the Factory pattern is typically unnecessary. You can just pass the function `(Input) -> Value` directly.

Your example doesn't show the caller, so it's hard to know precisely what function-based solution will work best, but in most cases, generic functions are a much better approach than protocols+associatedType+generics+inheritance. In particular, mixing class inheritance into associated types tends to get you into bad corners (because associated types and class inheritance are somewhat orthogonal approaches to polymorphism).

Comment: Thank you Rob for your answers, they helped me a lot to rethink some parts in my solution. I would agree with you about using protocols+associatedType+generics+inheritance if swift would not have limitations in using only generics+inheritance, like not being able to specify protocol as a concrete type for base class' generic constraint. I will write down my solution here a bit later, but if you want to talk more detailed, I will glad to.

Comment: Thanks. Swift's actual hope is that you don't use class inheritance, and instead just use protocols. (But that isn't to say that they've made class inheritance hard on purpose, or that you're wrong to be frustrated about them; Swift generics just aren't finished yet.)

Answer (score 0):

```
protocol ValueFactory: GenericFactory where Input: SomeInputImpl, Value: ValueProtocol {}
```

The Input should confirm SomeInputImpl.
As SomeInputImpl is struct type, so it can't be inherited. So you have to make it class or protocol

```
class SomeInputImpl {}
```

Then you can override the input variable

```
class Child<Factory: ValueFactory>: Base<Factory> {
override var input: Factory.Input {
    return SomeInputImpl() as! Factory.Input
}
```

}

Comment: This is exactly the way I did it for now, but it's not the solution I want because there are a lot of issues here. 
1. Generic constraint "where Input: SomeInput" will not matter there, because you can return anything you want, it will just work
2. If I return an instance of SomeInputImpl and then during the child creation define Factory, which has different input type, it will compile but will crash on force unwrap line
3. Force unwrap